# Conditional color change <s:SolidColor>

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, data-binding, flex4, itemrenderer

I am unable to get the DataGridItemRenderer to pass a color value to `<s:SolidColor`  based on the function containing an if statement based on the value of data.Bld_Type. Code below.  I am vey new to Flex and not sure what the problem or if this is the right way of doing it. Any help would be appreciated.  I have tried passing a hex number and color name. Neither work. Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:MXDataGridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
  xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
  focusEnabled="true">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
         import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        private var swatchCOL:uint;

        /** color function **/
        private function onLoad():void
        {
            if(data.Bld_Type == "Office")
                {
                swatchCOL="ee7970";
                //***swatchCOL="red";

                }    
            else if(data.Bld_Type == "Office/Warehouse")
                {
                swatchCOL="70b2ee";
                //***swatchCOL="blue";
                }
        }   
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>



    <s:Group left="10" right="10" top="10" bottom="10">
        <s:Rect width="25" height="25">
            <s:stroke>
                <s:SolidColorStroke color="green" weight="2"/>                        
            </s:stroke>
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="swatchCOL"/>
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>
    </s:Group>



</s:MXDataGridItemRenderer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the following:

```
[Bindable]
private var swatchCOL:uint;
```

And:

```
<s:fill>
    <s:SolidColor color="{swatchCOL}"/>
</s:fill>
```

And finally change color types:

```
if(data.Bld_Type == "Office")
                {
                swatchCOL=0xee7970;
                //***swatchCOL="red";

                }    
            else if(data.Bld_Type == "Office/Warehouse")
                {
                swatchCOL=0x70b2ee;
                //***swatchCOL="blue";
                }
```

Comment: This error after changes:1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type uint.

Comment: Ah sorry. Added one more code snippet to cast colors to `uint`.

Comment: The errors are gone. But it seems the Function is not executing. I may not have "private function onLoad():void" correct. When the <mx:DataGridColumn itemRenderer="renderers.SparkColorSwatchRenderer"/> calls the above mxml code the Function is suppose to execute.

Comment: You should override `public function set data(value:Object):void` and manage color values from there.

Comment: Really appreciate your help. (This may be over my head.) I am actually not rendering the datagrid or the data filling the datagrid. I am placing a rectangle with one of the columns and filling the rect with color swatchCol. Isn't public function set data(value:Object):void for changing the datagrid properties or data?

Comment: Think I may have gotten it:                     /** color function **/
   override public function set data(value:Object):void {      
    if(value != null)  {
     super.data = value;
     if(data.Bld_Type == "Office")
     { 
      swatchCOL=0xee7970;
      //***swatchCOL="red";
     }                 
     else if(data.Bld_Type == "Office/Warehouse")
     {
      swatchCOL=0x70b2ee;
      //***swatchCOL="blue";
     }
     else 
     { 
      swatchCOL=0x003399;
     }
    }   
    // Dispatch the dataChange event.
    dispatchEvent(new FlexEvent(FlexEvent.DATA_CHANGE));

Comment: I mean this property http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataRenderer.html#data which is available in this class http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/dataGridClasses/MXDataGridItemRenderer.html

Comment: What is this color coding 0xee7970?

Comment: It is a hex value in 0xRRGGBB format. The same as web #RRGGBB.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the easy way to do it:

```
override public function set data(value:Object):void {
    super.data = value;

    if(data.Bld_Type == "Office")
        swatchCOL.color = 0xee7970;
    else if(data.Bld_Type == "Office/Warehouse")
        swatchCOL.color = 0x70b2ee;
}
```

No binding required since the data setter gets called whenever the data changes for your item renderer.  Also, you need to set the "color" member rather than the SolidColor object itself.  And you can specify hex colors by prefacing the value with "0x".

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Option a) Using  (e.g. if colors are not dynamically generated):**

```
<s:states>
    <s:State name="stateA" />
    <s:State name="stateB" />
</s:states>
<!-- somewhere else in your code -->
<s:Rect id="bgFill" top="0" right="0" left="0" bottom="0">
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor color.stateA="#313131" color.stateB="#f4dede" />
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>
<!-- somewhere else in your code -->
<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[
if(data.Bld_Type == "Office")
            {
            this.currentState = "stateA"
            //***swatchCOL="red";

            }    
        else if(data.Bld_Type == "Office/Warehouse")
            {
            this.currentState = "stateB"
            //***swatchCOL="blue";
            }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

**Option b) Using AS3:**

```
var fillColor:SolidColor;
if(data.Bld_Type == "Office")
{
fillColor = new SolidColor(0xYOUR_HEX_COLOR);
bgFill.fill = fillColor;
}    
else if(data.Bld_Type == "Office/Warehouse")
{
fillColor = new SolidColor(0xYOUR_OTHER_HEX_COLOR);
bgFill.fill = fillColor;
}


<s:Group left="10" right="10" top="10" bottom="10">
    <s:Rect id="bgFill" width="25" height="25">
        <s:stroke>
            <s:SolidColorStroke color="green" weight="2"/>                        
        </s:stroke>
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="#ffffff"/> <!-- #ffffff is an example of a default color -->
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
</s:Group>
```