# How can I dynamically change the color of an XML button using AS3?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, button, colors, gradient

I've been struggling with this for a couple of days now, and it feels ridiculous. This isn't something new and I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. I've got three files, so here are some example snippets of how they're set up.

Viewer.mxml

```
<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[
  function changeColorState()
  {
    if(some condition is true)
    {
      myButton.colorState = TessaButton.PINK_COLORSTATE;
    }
    else
    {
      myButton.colorState = TessaButton.GRAY_COLORSTATE;
    }
  myButton.skin.setCurrentState('up');
  }
]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:VGroup>
  <TessaButton id="myButton"
               labelText="Example Button"
               click="doSomething(event)"
               skinClass="ButtonSkin" />
</s:VGroup>
```

TessaButton.mxml

```
<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[
  public static const PINK_COLORSTATE:String = 'Pink';
  public static const GRAY_COLORSTATE:String = 'Gray';

  public var colorState:String = PINK_COLORSTATE;//Default setting
]]>
</fx:Script>
```

ButtonSkin.mxml

```
<s:states>
  <s:State name="up" enterState="enterStateHandler(event)"/>
  <s:State name="down" />
  <s:State name="over" />
  <s:State name="disabled />
</s:states>

<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[
  //Pretend that these are all shades and tints of pink or gray, too lazy to make up examples
  public static const GE1_PINK_UP:uint = 0xffa2f7;
  public static const GE1_PINK_OVER:uint = 0xffa2f7;
  public static const GE1_PINK_DOWN:uint = 0xffa2f7;
  public static const GE2_PINK_UP:uint = 0xffa2f7;
  public static const GE2_PINK_OVER:uint = 0xffa2f7;
  public static const GE2_PINK_DOWN:uint = 0xffa2f7;

  public static const GE1_GRAY_UP:uint = 0xffa2f7;
  public static const GE1_GRAY_OVER:uint = 0xffa2f7;
  public static const GE1_GRAY_DOWN:uint = 0xffa2f7;
  public static const GE2_GRAY_UP:uint = 0xffa2f7;
  public static const GE2_GRAY_OVER:uint = 0xffa2f7;
  public static const GE2_GRAY_DOWN:uint = 0xffa2f7;

  private var fillColor1_up:uint = GE1_PINK_UP;//Default setting is pink
  private var fillColor1_over:uint = GE1_PINK_OVER;
  private var fillColor1_down:uint = GE1_PINK_DOWN;
  private var fillColor2_up:uint = GE2_PINK_UP;
  private var fillColor2_over:uint = GE2_PINK_OVER;
  private var fillColor2_down:uint = GE2_PINK_DOWN;

  private function enterStateHandler(e:FlexEvent):void
  {
    switch((hostComponent as ButtonProperties).colorState)
    {
      case 'Pink':
        fillColor1_up = GE1_PINK_UP;
        //And the rest set to the pink colors
        break;
      case 'Gray':
        fillColor1_up = GE1_GRAY_UP;
        //And the rest set to the gray colors
        break;
    }
]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:Rect id="fill">
  <s:fill>
    <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
      <s:GradientEntry color.up="{fillColor1_up}"
                       color.over="{fillColor1_over}"
                       color.down="{fillColor1_down}" />
      <s:GradientEntry color.up="{fillColor2_up}"
                       color.over="{fillColor2_over}"
                       color.down="{fillColor2_down}" />
    </s:LinearGradient>
  </s:fill>
</s:Rect>
```

I am under the impression that these colors in the gradient entries will dynamically change when the values of the fillColor variables are changed. In this case, those values get changed when there is a state change on the button to 'up'. By default, these buttons will appear pink. If whatever conditional I have is true, the colorState variable is gray and therefore the buttons should be gray. However, while running this, the trace statements I see in the enterStateHandler, I see that they are properly changing between gray and pink as I need, but they are still visually pink. I don't understand why. If anyone can point me in the correct direction on going about this or if someone can shed light on why this isn't working, please let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, I'd rather not use states to declare button colors as suggested as Option A by nvhdab to this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792051/conditional-color-change-ssolidcolor
I'd like to try this person's Option B, but I don't know how to alter the gradient entries. What would the syntax look like?

Comment: Add [Bindable] before each fillColor... definition. eg: [Bindable] private var fillColor1_over:uint = GE1_PINK_OVER;

Comment: And here's info on setting gradients: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/graphics/LinearGradient.html

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! <333

You should make that into an answer so I can mark it! It's so exciting now!!

Comment: okey dokey, i will ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mark the changable color variables as 'Bindable'. This tells Flex to keep an eye on the values, and when they change, to update anything else that is using them (such as your gradient).

So you need:

```
[Bindable] private var fillColor1_up:uint = GE1_PINK_UP;
[Bindable] private var fillColor1_over:uint = GE1_PINK_OVER;
[Bindable] private var fillColor1_down:uint = GE1_PINK_DOWN;
[Bindable] private var fillColor2_up:uint = GE2_PINK_UP;
[Bindable] private var fillColor2_over:uint = GE2_PINK_OVER;
[Bindable] private var fillColor2_down:uint = GE2_PINK_DOWN;
```